# How can i justify this multinomial coefficient identity?

Tags: co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, alternative-proof, multinomial-coefficients

$$\sum_{ k\ge 1 } \sum_{ (s_1,...,s_k) } \binom h{ s_1 ,..., s_k }=\binom{m-1}{h-1}$$
where the second summation is taken over all choices of the numbers

$${ s }_{ 1 },...,{ s }_{ k-1 }\ge 0,\quad {s  }_{k  }\ge 1$$

which satisfy the relations
$$\sum _{ i=1 }^{ k }{ { s }_{ i } } =h,\quad \sum _{ i=1 }^{ k }{ i{ s }_{ i } } = m$$

Answer (score 6):

Take a stick of length $m$ and partition it onto $h$ small sticks of positive integer lengths. The number of ways to do it equals $\binom{m-1}{h-1}$, as we choose $h-1$ cut points out of $m-1$. On the other hand, if $s_i$ denotes the number of small sticks of length $i$, and $k$ is the length if the longest small stick, we get the corresponding summand in LHS.

Comment: In other words, $\binom{m-1}{h-1}$ is the [number of compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)#Number_of_compositions) of $m$ into $h$ parts; and these compositions are tuples containing $s_1$ ones, $s_2$ twos, etc., for all possible choices of the $s_i$ as in the question.

Comment: Check this out http://mathoverflow.net/questions/264555/in-search-of-a-combinatorial-reasoning-for-a-vanishing-sum